# Insert + and - operators into an array from 1 to N, such as the array equals a number K.

Tags: algorithms, recursion, coding-theory, programming

I'm supposed to determine a **Recursive** way of finding all the possible combinations of the + and - operators inserted into an array from 1 to N, so that the final result will equal another given number K. An example would be:

For N = 6 and K = 3

1 + 2 + 3 - 4 - 5 + 6 = 3

1 + 2 - 3 + 4 + 5 - 6 = 3

1 - 2 - 3 - 4 + 5 + 6 = 3

I've been given a hint where I'm supposed to compute and F(N - 1)
which gives a K1 = K - N and K2 = K + N, and if the result reaches an F(0) = 1 then the resulted operators in order would compute to a correct answer.

I've tried this approach but so far it worked only in situations where all operators are identical (ex. 1 + 2 + 3 = 6), and can't manage to understand how to use it to solve the more complex situations. The algorithm should be implemented in a recursive method, without using data structures, just plain arrays and recursion.

Any idea how this would work or any other ideas?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $N$ and $K$ are given, so you'll want to think of your function as depending on both. We'll call the function $F(N, K)$. If $1 ... \pm N = K$, then $1 ... N - 1 = K \mp N$. So the solutions for $N$ and $K$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the solutions for $N - 1$ and $K - N$ together with the solutions for $N - 1$ and $K + N$. That means that $F(N, K) = F(N - 1, K + N) + F(N - 1, K - N)$.

You'll want to also figure out the base case(s) (what happens when N = 0?). Also, there's the subtle question about what to do with $1$. It seems to be implied that $1$ has to be positive (no negative sign inserted in front of it), so you may want to make $N = 1$ be the base case instead.

For an example, take $N = 4$ and $K = 6$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
F(4, 6) & = F(3, 2) + F(3, 10) \\
& = F(2, -1) + F(2, 5) + F(2, 7) + F(2, 13) \\
& = F(1, -3) + F(1, 1) + F(1, 3) + F(1, 7) + F(1, 5) + F(1, 9) + F(1, 11) + F(1, 15) \\
& = 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 \\
& = 1
\end{aligned}
$$

To actually figure out what combination of plus and minus would solve the problem, follow the tree upwards: $F(1, 1) \to F(2, -1) \to F(3, 2) \to F(4, 6)$. So it's $1 - 2 + 3 + 4 = 6$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes, It's true, we're talking only about positive integers, and only n + 1 arrays. I've taken N = 1 as a base case but I can't really figure out how to approach this on a more complex example, like how can i figure the operator order for a valid output.

Comment: @cipriRusu I've added in an example of how to compute this. You should be able to turn this into a recursive function to *count* the number of ways of solving the problem. Finding all the ways is probably not what you want, but it's still possible if you keep track of what paths in the recursion led to solutions.

Comment: Much more clear now, thank you!:)